# How to enable a menu only for a specific part in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I created a new submenu in Team menu as an extension of org.eclipse.ui.menus . The problem is that this submenu appears also in other plugins that extend org.eclipse.ui.menus.

The id's of these extensions are all different but still the menu appears.

How to enable the menu to appear only for some parts ?

**EDIT: Menu Definition:**

```
 <plugin>
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
  <command
        defaultHandler="DefaultHandler"
        id="menuItem.command"
        name="Menu Item"/> 
  </extension>
 <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
 <menuContribution allPopups="true" locationURI="popup:team.main?after=group3">
  <command
        commandId="menuItem.command"
        icon="icons/icon.png"
        id="menuItem.menu"
        style="push"/> 
  </menuContribution>
  </extension> 
    </plugin>
```

**EDIT: Menu definition of the plugin where the above definition also appears**

```
 <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution
        allPopups="true"
        locationURI="popup:com.comp.view1">
     <menu
           label="Open menu 1">
        <dynamic
              class="com.comp.views.OpenMenu1"
              id="com.comp.view">
        </dynamic>
     </menu>
     <menu
           label="Open menu 2">
        <dynamic
              class="com.comp.views.OpenMenu2"
              id="com.comp.view">
        </dynamic>
     </menu>
  </menuContribution>
```

Comment: Show us your menu definition.

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify `allPopups="true"` on the `menuContribution`. Either leave it out completely or use the default value of `false`.

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work, still appear on one of my other plugin which has a tableviewer with a context menu on right click per item...

Comment: How is that content menu defined?